# Dragging objects outside of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question has already been asked, but the solution doesn't work in my case. I have a little image carousel that's done in jQuery, but I want to be able to drag images outside of it. Right now, overflow must be set to hidden, since  only 5 images are displayed at a time, and the user clicks an arrow to advance through them. The solution given to the similar question was to set overflow to visible. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the "helper" parameter of the jquery UI draggable.

Please see the attached fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skylar/kh7LE/

The helper will create a new clone of the draggable that is outside of the context of the parent with visibility:hidden;

jQuery UI calls this "visual feedback" and you can read more about it here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback